# cacerts issue in JAVA and OPEN JDK 6

Tags: java

how can i build cacerts automatically in java , instead of using the Jre/lib/security/cacerts because openJDK didn't contain the cacerts file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own keystore using the [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html). Then you must import all CAs (Certificate Authorities) you need and either place the keystore in `<JRE>/lib/security` or explicitly set it using a system property. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work) for details.

Of course, you could reuse an existing keystore available in other JDKs.