# How can I access java trust store certs

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate

My server program uses the trust store for client certs which works fine for the two way handshake, however I would like to be able to get the certs from the trust store for other things. I noticed [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm) for Key stores. How do I do about it for trust stores?

I setup the trust store in following way for my SSL two way handshake, but I want to use the certs for something else.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "store.jts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "PASS);
```

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both trust stores and key store are KeyStore objects. Just the usage is different.
So, the example that you found should work for either a key store or a trust store, since they are objects of the same type.

Comment: I am talking about server code here, are you sure that's right?

Comment: My question didn't explicitly say this so sorry about that.

Comment: No, I was talking about client-side usage - I'm guessing that concepts  of 'keystore' and 'truststore' are reversed on the server. But even on the server, both the keystore and the truststore will be instances of KeyStore.