# Request a URL that client certificate authentication

Tags: java, ssl, urlconnection

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.p12");
ks.load(fis, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

This code works fine. But is any possibility to use keystore.jks for that case? For example, I have imported file.p12 into keystore.jks using pkcs12import tool with some alias. Then I use System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore" , "C:/Sun/SDK/jdk/jre/lib/security/keystore.jks"); and not write certificate path and password in java code and it take from that keystore.jks file

Comment: You can also specify a system property for the store type, so you don't need to import to JKS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - path to trustStore - set property doesnt work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work)

Comment: For system property I use keystore.jks where I have imported many certificates, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use a jks keystore to handle the certificates, an example of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work)