# Where do I place a .store file in netbeans in order to set it as a system property

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans

I leveraged a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4_JIIrMhIQ) that created a "Java Project"(new project wizard in Eclipse IDE). A .store file was generated for ssl connectivity. Where do I place this file in a netbeans "Java" project directory in order for it to be able to be set as a system proerty so that it does not throw the following error caused by not being able to locate the file. (the other two options from research stated that it could be an incorrect password, wrong filename, or unable to find location, the first two are false so I assume the latter).

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
>   implementation (algorithm: Default,...

Thanks

Comment: Re _"I leveraged a youtube video"_ => Update your post with a link to that video.

Comment: From the comments for the Youtube video => _System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","za.store"); works only when i have the za.store **in the same folder as the jar**_ ... Have you tried that? If you have, and it didn't work, then update your post accordingly.

Comment: An alternative approach is to put the file wherever you want, and then specify the path to it at runtime. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138670/2985643) to [java - path to trustStore - set property doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2138574/2985643)